# JSX doesn't evaluate integer in expression as boolean

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator, jsx

I'm used to write render optional Components like this:

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var length = 0;
    return <div>Foo {length && <Bar />}</div>;
  }
});
```

This shorthand `if` is mentioned in the [if/else in JSX guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) as  immediately-invoked function expression. However, since my latest update of React, it started to render `0` instead of `null`.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51mmhe27/)

Why is that happening?

Comment: Is `test` meant to be `length` in your example?

Comment: Try `{!!length && <Bar />}` to make the expression truth testing.  Basically coerce the length into a boolean value so that it can be used in an expression.

Comment: why not just `length ? <Bar /> : void(0)`

Comment: @AvraamMavridis IMO looks a bit uglier for complex components spanning over multiple lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&&` operator evaluates the left-hand expression first, and if the left-hand expression evaluates to something falsy it **returns the value of the left-hand expression** without evaluating further.

So `(0 && "Bar")` evaluates to `0` which is then rendered as a string. If all falsy values were discarded in the rendering then there would be no way to print a `0` in React, for example `length is { 0 }` would only print `length is`.

However `false`, `null` and `undefined` are discarded by React renderer if used as a child, and it's [exactly for this use case](http://web.archive.org/web/20160419195339/https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/false-in-jsx.html):

```
length is { 0 } // length is 0
length is { NaN} // length is NaN
length is { null } // length is
length is { false } // length is
length is { undefined } // length is
```

You need the left-hand expression of your `&&` operator to return one of those three, the simplest being a boolean:

```
( !!length && "Bar" ) // evaluates to false, doesn't print
( (length > 0) && "Bar" ) // evaluates to false, doesn't print
( (length != 0) && "Bar" ) // evaluates to false, doesn't print
( Boolean(length) && "Bar" ) // evaluates to false, doesn't print
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like

`length ? <Bar /> : void(0)`

React will not render something that is `undefined`, and with `void(0)` you guarantee that not any library had changed the value of `undefined`

Comment: The thing is, this has worked before. After updating react it didn't. I'm still trying to find out what change did cause this behavior..